# Iterating a bean in jsp using scriptlets and standard actions(no use of JSTL)

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I have been working on a document to describe the jsp scenario before the advent of JSTL. I Have to iterate the list and print its property using usebean standard action and scriptlet. Can anyone help me resolve this? In the tag i get the error duplicate local variable.

```
<% @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Player> list = (ArrayList<Player>) application
                    .getAttribute("PlayersList");
            for (Player player : list) { %> <jsp:useBean id="player"
        class="com.soccer.model.Player" scope="page">
                Name: <jsp:getProperty name="player" property="name" />
                Team: <jsp:getProperty name="player" property="team" />
                Age:  <jsp:getProperty name="player" property="age" />
                City: <jsp:getProperty name="player" property="city" />
    </jsp:useBean>
<%  } %>
```

Comment: The `player` variable is declared twice: once in the scriptlet loop and another time with `<jsp:useBean id="player" ...>`. You should remove the second declaration.

Comment: Then how do i access the bean to display its properties.